# Doctrine 2 cascade delete is not working? I have checked all the related anwsers on stackoverflow but they didn't worked

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use cascade remove in doctrine2, following are my entity classes but cascade delete is not working at all.

When I execute remove, record is getting deleted from user table but not from experience table. I am not getting any type of error but cascade remove is not working.

Parent class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ilook_user
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entities\experience", mappedBy="experiencesUser",  cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $usersExperience;
```

Child class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class experience
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entities\ilook_user", inversedBy="usersExperience")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ilook_user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
    private $experiencesUser;
```

Method I am using to remove record :

```
public static function softDeleteUser($user_id)
    {
        //Delete user
        $em = \Zend_Registry::get('em');
        $usr_obj = $em->find('\Entities\ilook_user', $user_id);
        $em->remove($usr_obj);
        $em->getConnection()->close();
        $em->flush();
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: It would probably help if we had more information about the problematic behavior "Not working at all" could mean quite a few different things. Are you receiving an error code? Incorrect output/behaviour? What debugging steps have you taken and what are your findings?

Comment: I mean record is getting deleted from user table but not from experience table. I am not getting any type of error but cascade remove is not working.

Comment: Could you please edit that information into your question? I'm not familiar with the technology but it would greatly help answerers who are. As it is your question looks like a code dump that you want debugged with little to no context and such questions tend to be heavily downvoted if not closed here.

Comment: Why are you closing connection before flushing?

Answer (score 0):

I thins this is because you are using cascading on inverse side of relation, not on owning side.

Hm I think relations are ok. You are closing connection before flushing.

Comment: You pointed out some thing very important that we should close connection after flushing but with this even my problem didn't solved.

Comment: try to clear cache. Sometimes annotations are caches and doctrine doesn't see any  changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use example below as reference. It works for me. I got rid of some annotations, properties, methods just to keep it short.

Brands (1) -> (N) Cars

So if you delete a Brand, all corresponding Cars will be deleted automatically.

**BRANDS**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="brands")
 */
class Brands
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cars", mappedBy="brands")
     */
    private $cars;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cars = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**CARS**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cars")
 */
class Cars
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brands", inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brands_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $brands;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to database, try this instead:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entities\experience", mappedBy="experiencesUser",  cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $usersExperience;
```

Comment: Good Answer inanzzz, But I have kept this as second option because  onDelete="CASCADE" works at database level, one have to create DB tables again from entity classes. Whereas  cascade={"remove"} will be applied in parent entity and works at entity level.

Comment: Did you try adding `orphanRemoval=true` as well? So it will be `........ mappedBy=............., cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true` [Read up on it here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal)

Comment: Yup tried orphanRemoval=true also , it is also not working. My scenario is that user register on site and if send confirmation mail fails it goes into if condition where user removed + experience removed, in this case cascade is not working. But when I comment out this if condition and execute that same remove query after registration process(in new http call), it works!